# Shell script to rename files by removing substring from initial name

Tags: shell

Need a Bash shell script that would rename multiple files by eliminating from the file name the variable length substring contained between two dots, including the first dot.
First example: initial file name is
"AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg" and the final file name is
"AAAAAAAA.jpg" -- substring ".BBBBB-BBB" was eliminated.
Second example: initial file name is
"mmmmmmmmmm.vvv-yyyyy.txt" and the final file name is
"mmmmmmmmmm.txt" -- substring ".vvv-yyyyy" was eliminated.

My script keeps appending the file extension to the initial name.
I am using CYGWIN on a Windows Surface laptop.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.jpg *.txt; do
  if [[ $file == *.*-*.* ]]; then
    new_file=${file%%.*.*-*}.${file##*.}
    mv "$file" "$new_file"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
rename -n 's/\.[^-]+-[^-]+(?=\.)//' AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg 
rename(AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg, AAAAAAAA.jpg)
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\.` | . |
| `[^-]+` | any character except: `-` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `-` | - |
| `[^-]+` | any character except: `-` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `\.` | . |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: Your script now appends the name twice.
From AAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.txt
we get AAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.txt.AAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.txt -- it does not remove the first dot and the following substring up to the file extension.

Comment: The Perl version is usually the way to go, the sed syntax is a killer feature

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the first pattern

Try a simpler version of the pattern to cut the prefix part

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.jpg *.txt; do
  if [[ $file == *.*-*.* ]]; then
    new_file=${file%%.*-*.*}.${file##*.}
    mv "$file" "$new_file"    
    #                             
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.*-*.{jpg,txt}}; do
    new_file=$(sed 's/\.[^.]\+\././' <<< "$file")
    mv "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

Comment: `echo $file` runs you into the problems described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). Always `echo "$file"` -- or just use `<<<"$file"` instead of echo at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks, fixed.  Missed those

Answer (score 0):

A simple version with only bash syntax:

```bash
for f in *.*-*.*; do
  [[ -e "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"
done
```

If you want to work only on some extensions (jpg, txt...):

```bash
for f in *.*-*.{jpg,txt}; do
  [[ -e "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"
done
```

The test `[[ -e ... ]]` is here just to protect against the absence of file.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE 1** for Mr. Pedantic :

```
    # gawk profile, created Sat Apr 22 04:14:46 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      FS = RS
     1      OFS = "\f\r\t\t\t"
     1      CONVFMT = "%.250g"
    }
  1  ($++NF = escQ(__ = $!_))^_ + \
     ($++NF =    shellQ(__))^_ + \
     ($++NF =  printfQ(__))^_

     3  function escQ(__,_)
    {
     3      return substr("", _ = "\47", 
                    -gsub(_, (_)  "\\" (_)_,__))__)
    }

     2  function shellQ(__, _)
    {
     2      return (_ = "\47") escQ(__)_
    }

     1  function printfQ(__, _)
    {
     1      return " printf " (_ = "\47") "%s"(_)" " shellQ(__)
    }
```

---

```
       nawk :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

      mawk1 :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

      mawk2 :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

   gawk -Se :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

   gawk -ce :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

   gawk -Pe :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

   gawk -Me :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

   gawk -re :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''

 gawk -p- -be :: ain't got nothin'
            ain'\''t got nothin'\''
            'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
             printf '%s' 'ain'\''t got nothin'\'''
```

---

```
echo $'AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg\nDDDDDDDDD.EEEEEEE-EEEEEE.TXT' | gtee >( gcat -n >&2 ) | 

     1  AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg
     2  DDDDDDDDD.EEEEEEE-EEEEEE.TXT
```

> ```
> nawk '(__=$-_) sub(".+", "mv -v \47"(__)"\47 \47&\47", 
>                    $!(NF = NF))^_' FS='[.].+[.]' OFS=.
>
> {m,g}awk      'sub(".+", "mv -v \47"($_)"\47 \47&\47", 
>                    $!(NF = NF))^_' FS='[.].+[.]' OFS=.
> ```

```
mv -v 'AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg' 'AAAAAAAA.jpg'
mv -v 'DDDDDDDDD.EEEEEEE-EEEEEE.TXT' 'DDDDDDDDD.TXT'
```

...then pipe the output to any light weight shell like `dash` for execution.

(`nawk` has a race condition so the original `$0` must first be saved, but neither `mawk` nor `gawk` has this issue)

Comment: How does this handle filenames containing literal quote characters within their text?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : that wasn't part of `OP`'s requirements. :::::::::::::::::::::         Go add another `gsub(/\47/, "&\\\\&&")` at the front if you're pedantic about it. And updated main post for mr. pedantic

Comment: "Doesn't break my system's security when the filenames are weird" is an _implicit_ requirement. If someone has to state it out loud in order for their system to not be insecure, then _almost everyone's_ systems will be insecure. Thus -- thank you for the update.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : if `posix` weren't so brain dead enough to permit `\n` in filenames life would be so much easier. As for filename security, it's not my job either to do someone else's homework.

Comment: If you consider making sure your advice is fit-to-purpose (and security _is_ a part of fit-to-purpose in the modern world) as "someone else's homework", are you sure it's appropriate to be offering that advice in a public forum where people are expected to be able to professionally apply the things they learn?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : fit to whose purpose ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : and rather ironic coming from the guy who actually believes `POSIX` is fit for anyone else's purpose other than the committee members themselves

Answer (score -2):

Check the below code.

Sample filenames taken from your question.

> AAAAAAAA.BBBBB-BBB.jpg
> mmmmmmmmmm.vvv-yyyyy.txt

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.*.{txt,jpg}
    do
        mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F "." '{print $1"."$NF}')
    done
```

**Output:**

```
# ls -rt | tail -2
mmmmmmmmmm.txt
AAAAAAAA.jpg
```

Comment: `for file in *.*.{txt,jpg}`

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)